# Android layout help customizing according to image

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout in android according to the image however whatever i try is just wrong.

Here's my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomright"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#E5E5E5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"                 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/bottomright" />

    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >  

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="102dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textSize="30sp"     
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxLines="7"                               
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topright"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"  
            android:gravity="top|right"                                     
            android:textSize="90sp"
            android:text="topright" />           

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here what i want to get. Maybe it is wrong to use LinearLayout? Better user Relative?

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating static xml layout's are very easy. I guess you haven't tried googling yourself.
anyways, with respect to the image, here is the code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```